# User.Identity.IsAuthenticated is false even after successful form authentication and setauthcookie

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5, forms-authentication, wif

I have two Controllers TokkenIssuer and Login.
I have used [authorize] for a method A in TokkenIssuer which takes to Login controller's view and then to Login controller's Login action.

**Login Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Login(string user,string password,string returnUrl)
    {
        FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(user, true);
        if (FormsAuthentication.Authenticate(user, password))
        {

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(returnUrl) && Request.UrlReferrer != null)
                returnUrl = Server.UrlEncode(Request.UrlReferrer.PathAndQuery);

            return RedirectToAction("B", "TokenIssuer");
        }
        return View();
    }
```

From Login i am redirectingtoaction B in Tokenissuer Controller.
I came to know User.Identity.IsAuthenticated will becomet true after a redirect to another controller but i am unable to fetch User object nor find the User.Identity.IsAuthenticated as true in my redirected controller (TokenIssuer).

**TokenIssuer Controller**

```
[Authorize]
    public ActionResult A()            //takes to Login view
    {
     return View();       
    }
    public ActionResult B()           //Redirected from Login controller
    {
       if(User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)                  // Getting False
        {
           string user = User.Identity.Name;
        }
    }
```

how to resolve this issue?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It took a lot of time to find the issue.

I came to know, In VS 2013 or above when we create a web application by default it adds the following code in web.config file which disables the form / claim based authentication to create the user object.

```
<module>
    <remove name = "FormsAuthentication"/>
</module>
```

So Comment or Remove.This helped me.

Answer (score 0):

It will be false until the next request.

Here's a good explanation: http://forums.asp.net/t/1177741.aspx

In short, the User object is set earlier in the ASP.NET pipeline, long before the requested ASP.NET page's code is executed. Now, on the subsequent visit, the ASP.NET runtime will see the forms authentication ticket and User.Identity.IsAuthenticated will be true, but not on this request.

Reference: https://www.experts-exchange.com/questions/28063988/User-Identity-IsAuthenticated-is-false-after-a-successful-Login-Validation.html